# Ruby error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a two page timesheet submission app. So far the form works and you get the loading icon for one second, then it moves to the thank you page. The error occurs when attempting to restart the process, going back to the first page. I get the above error and it points to line 6 of the below code.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show_data
    @email  = params[:timesheet][:email]
    sleep(1.0)
  end
end
```

Here is the code for the First page.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "code.js" %>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Submit Timesheet</h1>
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
  </div>
  <%= form_for :timesheet, :action=>"show_data", :onsubmit => "return validationEvent();" do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email:", onFocus: "this.placeholder=''", onBlur: "this.placeholder='Email:'", :id=>"email" %>
      <%= f.label "Invalid Email", :id=>"invalid", :class=>"invalid" %>
      </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.text_area :message, placeholder: "Message (optional):", onFocus: "this.placeholder=''", onBlur: "this.placeholder='Message (optional):'" %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label("What type of work is this for?") %>
    </p>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="option">Time working on visual effects for movie</div>
      <div class="option">Time spent reviewing the work of a junior artist</div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <%= f.button "Clear", type: :reset, :id=>"clear" %>
      <%= f.submit "Next", :id=>"next", :onclick =>"return validationEvent();" %>
    </p>

    <%= debug params %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the code for the completion page.

```
<h1> Timesheet Submitted </h1>
<%= form_for :timesheet, :action=>"root" do |f| %>
  Thank you <%= @email %>!
  <p>
    <%= f.button "Start Over", :id=>"restart", :onsubmit=>"index" %>
  </p>
<%= debug params %>
<% end %>
```

I've looked online and still cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a Timesheet model? If not, `form_for :timesheet` or `form_for @timesheet` won't work. If you have a model, please share the model code. If you do not have a model, you can use form_tag and manually generate the params array. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag for form_tag

Comment: @Anand that's not true, you can use form for with a symbol.

Comment: What params hash do you get on the `show_data` action?  It seems `params[:timesheet]` is nil

Comment: @j-dexx - you are right. Edited my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to first page, you have empty params. To fix error you could write something like

```
def show_data
    if params.has_key?(:timesheet) && params[:timesheet].has_key?(:email)
        @email  = params[:timesheet][:email]
    end
    sleep(1.0)
end
```